# mongodb - map/reduce with pagination

Tags: mongodb, pagination, mapreduce

I am using Mongo 3.4 and I am performing a map-reduce operation on a 100m document collection. I can paginate the M/R by:

1. placing it inside a `while` loop,
2. where I can perform a find().limit().skip(),
3. and use the `query` M/R operator to filter input documents

This will allow me to write a log line every N documents. But is it a good / common approach to M/R, or should I just run the entire operation in one go?

Thanks,

Comment: The real answer of course is "don't use mapReduce". In any release for the last 4 years you likely really should be using [`.aggregate()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) instead, and if for some reason you cannot use aggregate then your data really should be restructured so you can.  Whilst "limit" is an option for mapReduce this applies to **"input"** and NOT the result. So in brief *"You're doing it the wrong way"*. You should instead be asking *"How do I do this with aggregate?"* if you're looking for productive outcomes.

Comment: I am using .aggregate() where I can. In this case I need to use regex, I am performing analytics, the analytic tests change often, as is the nature of analytics. Therefore map-reduce is necessary.

Comment: Which part of "Cannot do it" is difficult to understand then? So like I said, if you "think" you need mapReduce for something, then your process is likely wrong. This gives you two options 1. Change what you are doing, and ask questions about that to get some input on how you can get your desired result in a better way. 2. Send your mapReduce out to a collection, just like it's original intended purpose was designed for. Then you can "paginate" that result collection to your heart's content.

Comment: This question is utterly unrelated to the "duplicate" you posted. I have no idea what you are talking about when you say "cannot do it". I am already sorting _before_ the MR, that's how I paginate the inputs to the MR operation. I am already sending out to a collection using $out since MR can append to an $out collection _unlike_ `.aggregate()`. I don't think you understand what I am asking, so here goes again: is chunking up a MR operation common practice, and are there any benefits/detriments?

Comment: Yes I do understand what you are asking. Perhaps you should start reading the references to understand why this is the only answer. Already gave you pointers on what you "should" be asking as an alternative. The only way to "paginate" a mapReduce result is via a collection where the results are written. This is what the existing answer says, and so does the linked JIRA issue contained within that answer which is still unresolved because there is no immediate intent to change this.